# How to aggregate data several times on the same table

Tags: r, aggregate

I am working in R and have a list with 3 columns:

```
Fruit     Drawer      Amount
Banana    Top         1
Peach     Top         2
Apple     Top         3
Banana    Mid         4
Peach     Mid         5
Apple     Mid         6
Banana    Bottom      7
Peach     Bottom      8
Apple     Bottom      9
```

and I want to create the smallest ratio of fruit type (ex. bananas) in each drawer (ex. Top) to total fruit (all the bananas).

I am using table:

`x <- table(fruits)`

but I get a type of data that I don't know how to work with.

Ultimately I want to get "bananas per drawer" divided by the "total bananas" in all the drawers. I guess I could do it column by column but I am sure there are better ways to go about it. Any suggestion?

Sorry for any etiquette mishaps, I haven't been programming for long.

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? What is your expected output based on these data?

Comment: The  `data` argument of the `aggregate` statement is missing and  `FUN` is the third, not second argument.

Comment: and what do you mean by it's not quick enough for you

Comment: - Heroka, nothing, I am trying to make it as efficient as possible, this is a huge database (2 GB)

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself correctly.
I don't know how to do the  "bananas per drawer" divided by the "total bananas". 
I guess I could do it one by one but I am sure there are better ways to go about it.

Comment: You should probably edit your question and add the expected output for the sample data you provided. That will make it easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

fruit__drawer = 
"Fruit     Drawer      Amount
Banana    Top         1
Peach     Top         2
Apple     Top         3
Banana    Mid         4
Peach     Mid         5
Apple     Mid         6
Banana    Bottom      7
Peach     Bottom      8
Apple     Bottom      9" %>% 
  read.table(text = . , header = TRUE)

fruit =
  fruit__drawer %>%
  group_by(Fruit) %>%
  summarize(Amount.fruit = sum(Amount)) %>%
  mutate(Proportion.overall = Amount.fruit / sum(Amount.fruit))

result = 
  fruit__drawer %>%
  left_join(fruit) %>%
  group_by(Drawer) %>%
  mutate(Proportion= Amount/sum(Amount),
         Proportion.ratio = Proportion/Proportion.overall)
```

Comment: Thank you very much bramtayl! 

Where does this go? I don't understand it

%>% 
  read.table(text = . , header = TRUE)

Comment: Hi bramtayl, this is exactly was I am trying to do. The first part of the command works, however the second one gives me an error: Error in tbl_vars(y) : object 'fruit' not found. The data is a data.frame with 2 factors and an integer. Why do you think? any suggestion in what I should look into? Thank you!

Comment: fruit in this case should be referring to the result of the middle chunk of code. That is, if the middle chunk worked, then fruit should exist.

Comment: One more thing actually, the resulting data frame does not include the Proportion and Proportion ratio variables. How do I make them stay?

Comment: Assign the result at the end to a variable, see edit.

Comment: Thank you. I realize these are silly questions, but I am still a little confused about the %>% construct.